# Generating Laravel 5 rules from database entries

Tags: laravel-5

I want to dynamically generate Laravel rules from settings in a database table. How to go about this?

```
protected $rules = [
    'firstname' => ['required'],
    'lastname' => ['required'],
    'email' => ['required']
];
```

Can I just do a get() from the database within $rules? Or should I create a function that creates the array like:

I started making this within the function that handles the form POST:

```
private function getFormRules($slug = null) {
    $values = Value::where('element_field_id', 2)->where('value_char', $slug)->get();
    $rules_array = '';
    foreach($values as $value) {
            $rules_array .= "'".$value['form-field-name']."' => ['required'],";
        }
    }
    $rules = "[".rtrim($rules_array, ",")."]";
    return $rules;
}
```

Then in the form function I make the rules by:

```
public function form($slug = null) {
    $rules = $this->getFormRules($slug);
    // then validate, if not OK, show the form with errors
    // if validated, submit form
    // etc etc etc
}
```

The string that is returned using this function is:

```
['email' => ['required'], 'address' => ['required'], 'lastname' => ['required'], 'firstname' => ['required'], 'phone' => ['required']]
```

And my main question is, can I use this to validate my form.

Comment: Can you add more info? I don't understand the database settings thing.

Comment: Yes I can Santiago... I have added what I created thus far to my question...

Comment: Just try it with test data.